# ng-change triggers belatedly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im making search for my application, I have search input which lists items.

Here you can see input which triggers **runSearch()** function in controller.

```
        <div class="item item-input">
            <input type="search" placeholder="" ng-model="query" ng-change="runSearch()">
        </div>
```

The **runSearch()** functions runs some search functions, which add found items to $scope.results, these results are printed in html after.

```
        LocalDB.getArchitects($scope.query).then(function (architects) {
                // add architects to results ($scope.results)
        });
        LocalDB.getBuildings($scope.query).then(function (buildings) {
                // add buildings to results
        });
        LocalDB.getCities($scope.query).then(function (cities) {
                // add cities to results ($scope.results)
        });
```

The problem is, that shown results ignore last character in input. Looks like ng-change triggers just a little bit late, or the $scope.query is a character late.

**Explaination:**

Search input is: **ABCD**

results should be: **ABCD**something

but actual results are **ABC**something

the last character in search input (**D** in this case) is ignored.

Comment: How are you "adding buildings to results"?  If your query for "ABC" takes longer to return than your query for "ABCD" then you will end up with results for ABC.  You really should have a short delay after changes occurring which indicates the user has stopped typing and only then do the search

Comment: adding buildings takes some time, it is linear cycle. Where Im I supposed to put the delay? When I put ng-model-options="{debounce:3000}" into html, then it does wait but results are same.

Comment: Have you tried just waiting until the user hits return or a GO button before doing the search, and does it work that way?  Unless you are doing a typeahead it seems like you should be waiting for the user to complete what they are searching for. If you are looking for typeahead behavior try using the typeaheads provided by bootstrapui or other angular libs as they work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding results to `itemsToShow` and then refreshing `$scope.results` every 1 sec.

```
$interval(function () {
    $scope.results = itemsToShow;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: A better solution would be to use `debounce` or `updateOn` via `ngModelOptions`.

Comment: @lux I have tried debounce, but it didnt really change anything (only slowed it down a bit)